# How to realize audio and video curve speed change？

Tags: avaudioplayer, curve

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3Yv3.jpg)

I have an mp4, and I want to know how this curve speed change is achieved; including how it uses key frames to change the total duration?
There is no principle and method of its implementation on the Internet.